# Reselect - use custom argument for second selector in createSelector

Tags: javascript, reselect

I have a following case:

```
const firstSelector = (store, userId) => { ... };
const secondSelector = (store, moneyId) => { ... };

const selector = createSelector(
   firstSelector,
   secondSelector, // it doesn't accept `userId` but `moneyId` which is inside 
                   // `firstSelector` (first.moneyId)
   (first, second) => { ... },
);
```

As you can see, everything would be great if only I could pass custom argument to the second selector.

This `secondSelector` accepts `moneyId` as the second argument and it's `first.moneyId`, actually.

Am I able to use argument on the second combined selector, which is actually the value of what `firstSelector` did return?

Answer (score 2):

```
const firstSelector = (store, userId) => ({ moneyId: 'moneyIdFromFirst' });
const secondSelector = (store, moneyId) => ({ second: 'selector', moneyId });

const intermediateSelector = (store, userId) => createSelector(
  firstSelector,
  (first) => secondSelector(store, first.moneyId)
)(store, userId)

const selector = createSelector(
  firstSelector,
  intermediateSelector,
  secondSelector, // not longer necessary
  (first, second, third) => 
    console.log(first, second, third)
);
```

Achieving output:

```
Object { moneyId: "moneyIdFromFirst" }
Object { second: "selector", moneyId: "moneyIdFromFirst" }
Object { second: "selector", moneyId: "userId" }
```

The `intermediateSelector` returns the value `moneyIdFromFirst` instead of `secondSelector`'s `userId`.

Thanks to @Joseph Sikorski, you can use minimalistic one-function solution:

```
const selectorOneFunc = createSelector(
  firstSelector,
  (state, userId) =>
    secondSelector(state, firstSelector(state, userId).moneyId),
  (first, second) =>
    console.log("selectorOneFunc:", first, second)
);
```

[image: Edit oz9wnlrny]

Comment: Thanks, however I would prefer to do it with just one selector (one func)

Comment: Since the input selectors expect different arguments, this is about as close as you'll get: `const selector = createSelector(firstSelector, (state, userId) => secondSelector(state, firstSelector(state, userId).moneyId), (first, second) => {...})`

Comment: I have updated the answer with Joseph Sikorski's suggestion, you may check if this is your desired solution @Patrickkx